# SAS homogeneity of variance

Tags: statistics, sas

I have different categorical data in which are CLASS and I want to test homogeneity of variance using `Proc GML` and it doesn't display the output of the test

```
Proc GLM DATA=MYLIB.musictask;  
  CLASS TASK Music_Type Child_number_ID;  
  MODEL Emotional_state = Task Music_Type Child_number_ID Task*Music_Type Task*Child_number_ID Music_Type*Child_number_ID;  
  Means TASK Music_Type Child_number_ID/ hovtest=levene;  
run;  
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an ODS Output statement. The ODS table names for Proc GLM include Bartlett, which is the test underlying the HOVTEST= option. So, add these lines to your code:

```
ods output bartlett=hovtestoutput;
run;
proc print data=hovtestoutput;
run;
```

Or something like that.

Comment: "Thanks" but this is not working either. I tried different methods but still fails

Comment: Can anyone provide any suggestion regarding the question stated

Comment: @user3552266  That code works. You're making some other kind of errors. Please provide the specific code -- all of it -- and the error message(s). Thank you.